# Authenticate Mongodb and Auto Backup of Database on Server Using Cron Job

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backup, database-backups, database

1. How to secure MongoDB database with authentication?
2. How automated backup of Mongodb database using Node.js cron job and store on server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the steps provided on below links.

[Secure Your Mongodb Database](http://www.solutionanalysts.com/blog/8-simple-steps-to-install-mongodb-with-authentication-on-ec2-ami-linux/)

[Backup of your Mongodb Database on server](http://www.solutionanalysts.com/blog/auto-backup-mongodb-database-with-nodejs-on-server/)